# How to populate a template docx or odt in android with library?

Tags: android, templates, docx, docx4j, xdocreport

I'm making an android app and I want to fill a table template inserted in to a docx document.
I'm trying the XdocReport library but I can't accomplish. 
I also read about JODRreports and Docx4j but I don't find info about using on Android. Other alternative that I found is Aspose, but is very expensive for personal use. 
Someone has succeeded with some library?
Thanks

Comment: For using XDocReport with android, is it the same problem than this issue https://code.google.com/p/xdocreport/issues/detail?id=351 If it that android doesn't support SPI Provider?

Comment: It is possible to run docx4j on android, but requires intermediate to advanced skills:- http://www.docx4java.org/blog/2012/05/jaxb-can-be-made-to-run-on-android/

Comment: Thank you! I've done it with this: http://www.docx4java.org/blog/2012/05/jaxb-can-be-made-to-run-on-android/ 
You have to use exactly the same libraries and everything works.